# custom field suit new post with in custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field

how can i use Custom Field Suite (CFS) https://uproot.us/ to create new posts in post type. what am trying to do is create a music albums using post then create new post based off the tracks in the album. i want to manage the track in the album post but have each track in the album as a new post type.

Answer (score 0):

My method for this would be:

1. Create custom post types for Albums and Tracks, using either the
   [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin, or just declaring them in
   functions.php (it's [not that hard](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)).
2. Use the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin and create a "[Relationship](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/)" field. You can restrict it to appear on Albums, and to accept only Tracks. The interface will allow you to order them by drag-and-drop.

PS: the CFS plugin seems to do pretty much the same as ACF. But I'm more familiar with the latter, so that's what I would use.